# CakePHP 2.x - Accessing $_POST data within controller (REST POST request)

Tags: php, ajax, rest, cakephp, post

I'm creating an API using Cakephp 2.x that needs a POST request to post some data to the server however when I'm posting (using Postman) to `127.0.0.1/appname/api/confirm` with `code=123` in the post parameters my `$_POST` is an empty array.

My route works, I can see variables that I declare and output within the controller, and I've checked that the parameters are being passed in the request by using the chrome developer console checking the network data.

```
Router::connect('/api/confirm', array('controller' => 'awesomeController', 'action' => 'confirm'));

<?php        
class AwesomeController extends AppController {
     public function confirm() {
         $this->autoRender = false;
         $this->layout = 'ajax';
         pr($_POST);     
     }
} 
?>
```

I've got my endpoints for the get requests to work just fine, it only seems to be POST data.

Not quite sure why `$_POST` wouldn't even be available and I'm sure it's something ridiculously silly I've overlooked!

** Edit **

I've attempted the following without success:

```
$this->request->query
$this->request->data
$this->request->params
```

I have another method whereby I use GET along with ?parameter=value etc and I am able to use one of the above calls to retrieve the data.

Comment: Not CakePHP related, Cake parses parameters from $_POST. If that one is empty, php didn't receive them. Are you using some JS framework to post requests? (liek AngularJS $http service)

Comment: No, I'm just sending a straight curl request via postman rest client (chrome app) which I have used for testing quite a while now. I did find it strange that the $_POST was empty.

Comment: Just a quick thought, are there any php related ini stuff to do with post data that might be turned off? I had it working locally on another machine (php 5.5.4) I'm currently on xamp using 5.4.19

Comment: Can you see some headers or submitted form data from postman?

Comment: Yeah I looks like it's being sent. I've also checked the response object in cakephp and found something under raw (can't remember the name)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the variables should be in

```
$this->request->query
```

Try using URLs like `api/confirm?code=123`, and they will be in `request->query`

Comment: That is exactly what I thought however I've inspected the $this->request object and the $_POST data is inside the Cake Request Object ([_input:protected] => code=123) but not within the parameters for [query]

Comment: what about $this->request->data and $this->request->params ?

Comment: These are all empty also. Could it be with how I'm posting the data? I don't use url parameters e.g. /api/confirm?code=123. I actually use form data to post the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong since I am pretty new to cakePHP but since you set:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

so the view is not rendered automatically to set the view to ajax layout.
Isn't it necessary to call:

```
$this->render();
```

After setting the layout as said [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arender)?

Well, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody come here one day by googling, just had the same problem.

Had a REST Controller, called with URL /rest/something/cool.json

Method called inside RestController.php, had output, but no POST, no REQUEST.

Tried with code=123, sending direct JSON, the only way to make it works was to set Content-Type to application/json and to send actual working JSON : Cake seems to validate prior to anything, sending raw data seems useless.